# What is the difference between console and coloredConsole appenders in log4net?

Tags: c#, log4net

What is the difference between **Console** and **ColoredConsole** appenders in log4net?
Except for ability to color message of course :)

Is it more safe to use normal Console Appender? Which appender is faster?

In the documentation: [Colored](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.ColoredConsoleAppender.html)
and [Console](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender.html)

it is written that for Colored: 
`NOTE: This appender writes directly to the application's attached console not to the System.Console.Out or System.Console.Error TextWriter`

But For console `NOTE: This appender writes each message to the System.Console.Out or System.Console.Error`

Does this mean something important for me as a user?

Comment: The documentation that you link to already gives the answer. Specifically, the bit that says 'The System.Console.Out and System.Console.Error streams can be programmatically redirected (for example NUnit does this to capture program output).

This appender will ignore these redirections because it needs to use Win32 API calls to colorize the output. To respect these redirections the ConsoleAppender must be used.'

Answer (score 1):

After reading the documentation for both appenders [ColoredConsoleAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.ColoredConsoleAppender.html) and [ConsoleAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender.html) I would say that the only difference is the option for coloring of the output.

You can configure the output in the config file as shown in the documentation.

Comment: That's it. You can e.g. print ERROR logs red for easier reading

Comment: Is there something else? beside coloring?

Comment: @fen What are you expecting? Blinking text? Music? :)

Comment: maybe some drinks? But in the documentation I've read that "NOTE: This appender writes directly to the application's attached console not to the System.Console.Out or System.Console.Error TextWriter" ConsoleAppender writes to NOTE: This appender writes each message to the System.Console.Out or System.Console.Error.